# RecyclerView with header

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to write a simple app with a list of TextViews (in RecyclerView) with a header. Header must resize after scrolling. If I srcoll a list I need to set text size of header to bigger.

First I thought I will use a LinearLayout with TextView (header) and RecyclerView (list). But when I set a onScrollListener on my recyclerview and use setTextSize(scroll) on my header (textview) after scrolling everything was "jumping" beacause height of header and list was changing when text in header was too big and used second and more lines.

So I invented that I will make only RecyclerView with dynamicly changed size of first eleement of item and it works (mostly) but I need to make it "sticky" to left it after scrolling in first place of screen.

Has anyone any idea how to make recyclerview with a header?
This is my code of second idea:
MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemRecycleAdapter());
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }

        private int MAX_FONT = 30;
        private int MIN_FONT = 15;
        private int MAX_HEIGHT = 150;

        int currentLineCount = 1;

        int totalOffset = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            totalOffset += dy;

            View child = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
            TextView textView = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.headerText);
            textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, offsetToFontSize(totalOffset));


        }

        public int offsetToFontSize(int offset) {

            if (offset > MAX_HEIGHT)
                return MIN_FONT;

            float step = ((float) (MAX_FONT - MIN_FONT)) / MAX_HEIGHT;

            return (int) (MIN_FONT + ((float) (MAX_HEIGHT - offset)) * step);

        }

    });


}
```

RecyclerAdapter:

```
public static final List<Item> Items = new ArrayList<Item>();

private int MAX_FONT = 30;
private int MIN_FONT = 15;
private int MAX_HEIGHT = 150;


static {
    Items.add(new Item("DUŻY TYTUL n you attach it to the view by calling n you attach it to the view by calling", "", ""));
    Items.add(new Item("", "n you attach it to the view by calling n you attach it to the view by calling ", "Lorem ipsum dolar"));
    Items.add(new Item("", " by calling n you att by calling n you attach it to the ach it to the ", "Lorem ipsum dolar"));
    Items.add(new Item("", "Long text test", "Lorem ipsum dolar"));
    Items.add(new Item("", "Long text testLong text test", "Lorem ipsum dolar"));
    Items.add(new Item("", "Long text test", "Lorem ipsum dolar"));
    Items.add(new Item("", "Long text test", "Lorem ipsum dolar"));
    Items.add(new Item("", "Long text test", "Lorem ipsum dolar"));
    Items.add(new Item("", "Long text test", "Lorem ipsum dolar"));
}


@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item_element, parent, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = Items.get(position);
    if (position > 0){
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.header.setText((item.mHeader));
    holder.text1.setText(item.item1);
    holder.text2.setText(item.item2);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Items.size();
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = Items.get(position);
    if (position > 0){
        holder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    holder.header.setText((item.mHeader));
    holder.text1.setText(item.item1);
    holder.text2.setText(item.item2);

}

public void cos(ItemViewHolder holder, int totalOffset){
    holder.header.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, offsetToFontSize(totalOffset));
}

public int offsetToFontSize(int offset) {

    if (offset > MAX_HEIGHT)
        return MIN_FONT;

    float step = ((float) (MAX_FONT - MIN_FONT)) / MAX_HEIGHT;

    return (int) (MIN_FONT + ((float) (MAX_HEIGHT - offset)) * step);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Items.size();
}
```